# Using declaration of constructors compromises access specifiers and isn't consistent with other types of members

Tags: gcc, visual-c++, clang, c++17, icc

Today I've learned a new shocking reality, all popular compilers (those I could put my hands on, on godbolt.org) are good with this code (it compiles) and I can't explain why:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A()
    { }
};

class B : private A
{
    using A::A;
};

int main()
{
    auto b = B{};
    return 0;
}
```

[view on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/sxYnPxv4M)

My reasoning: it should fail at `auto b = B{};`, since `using` declaration is in private scope, therefore that's where the constructors, implicitly provided by the compiler, as the result of that `using`, should go.

Be it any other member: function or variable, it's access modifier would be determined, based on where is the `using` declaration is placed (`public`/`protected`/`private` section).

But, now, this doesn't compile:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A(int)
    { }
};

class B : private A
{
    using A::A;
};

int main()
{
    auto b = B{1};
    return 0;
}
```

[view on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/EeYnzf63T)

And that's predictable and intuitive:

```
<source>:15:14: error: calling a protected constructor of class 'A'
    auto b = B{1};
             ^
<source>:4:5: note: declared protected here
    A(int)
```

But, unfortunately, it doesn't compile (as IS intuitive I believe) for other reasons, because this doesn't as well:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A(int)
    { }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A;
};

int main()
{
    auto b = B{1};
    return 0;
}
```

[view on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/bcdraq37M)

---

It seems that `using` declaration is either badly worded or badly understood. Unfortunately, many compilers (some of them, fortunately, not longer, in a HEAD) also struggle with `friend` permissions:

```
class C;

class A
{
    friend class C;

protected:
    A(int)
    { }
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    using A::A;
};

class C
{
public:
    B make_b()
    {
        return B{1};
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto b = C{}.make_b();
    return 0;
}
```

[view on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/fsqd9GxM5)

Can some language lawyer analyse this and shed some light? Am I wrong with my assumptions and this is how it should be?

Comment: Right now all your assumptions are implicitly described by your code only. It would perhaps help if you would put your assumptions into words as well. I.e., what your assumed understanding of `using` is compared to the observed behavior. Besides, I'd look askance at your first example as well, as it doesn't explicitly *call* A's (defaul) constructor from B's...

Comment: [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration) explains what's going on rather nicely.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Unfortunately, that leaves the mystery for the first case. It shouldn't compile. Given `it is accessible if it would be accessible when used to construct an object of the corresponding base class`, for this you must be able to construct `A{}` from `main()`. But it's not possible (error, as expected).

Comment: @GreenScape I address this in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[class.default.ctor](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor)

> If there is no user-declared constructor for class X, a non-explicit constructor having no parameters is implicitly declared as defaulted

There are no user-declared constructors for class `B`. The constructor that `B` inherits from `A` is not a constructor for `B`, it is a  constructor for `A`. Inherited constructors are considered when looking up constructors for the derived class, but they are still not constructors for the derived class.

<s>The standard never explicitly says that inheriting constructors does or does not create similar constructors for the derived class. The standard does say that the constructors for the base class are made available for lookup and overload resolution *as if* they were constructors for the derived class. This IMO means that they are not considered constructors for the derived class, though it would be better if the standard explicitly said that. At any rate, the compilers seem to interpret it this way.</s>

**Edit** This is a [change from C++14](https://eel.is/c++draft/diff.cpp14.class), where inherited constructors were injected ino the derived class. Even in C+14, these constructors were *implicitly declared* and not user-declared.

Thus `B` has a *public* implicitly declared as defaulted default constructor, regardless of whatever it inherits from `A`.

[namespace.udecl](https://eel.is/c++draft/namespace.udecl#16)

> Base-class constructors considered because of a using-declarator are accessible if they would be accessible when used to construct an object of the base class; the accessibility of the using-declaration is ignored.

Thus `A::A(int)` is not accessible when constructing `B`, even though the `using` declaration that imports it is accessible.

Comment: That annex explains everything. Thanks a lot. Although, I call this decision by whoever made it, a nasty one. This is just another gotcha that you have to know about. Because it's not what someone (me) would expect on the first glance. Simply due to inconsistency with other uses of `using`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the `using` statement if that it only *imports* the declarations of constructors but will not change their *visibility* in the sense public, protected, private.

A more robust way would be to declare a public ctor:

```
class B : public A
{
public:
    B(int i): A(i){};
};
```

That way you use a protected member from an explicitely declared public one.

---

Reference:

The n4860 draft for C++20 says at 9.9 The using declaration [namespace.udecl] §1

> ...If the using-declarator does not name a constructor, the unqualified-id is
> declared in the declarative region in which the using-declaration appears as a synonym for each declaration
> introduced by the using-declarator. **If the using-declarator names a constructor, it declares that the class inherits the set of constructor
> declarations** introduced by the using-declarator from the nominated base class.

Only non constructors would have been declared public that way.

Comment: Isn't the mechanics of being able to 'inherit' constructors *specifically* exists to avoid the boilerplate of declaring a 'forwarding' constructors? Can you provide a specific clause from the standard that days that `it only imports the declarations`?

Comment: Yes, it changes the *visibility*, it says nothing about inheriting the access specifiers.

Comment: @GreenScape: the quoted paragraph says that the constructors are *inherited*. My understanding is that the normal inheritance rules are applied: public inheritance of a protected member is still a protected member.

Comment: yes, this definition is vague. Unfortunately it doesn't explain case (1). It shouldn't compile then?

Answer (score -1):

The reason is the compiler will add a default public non-parameter constructor if there is no one in the class. Your first case will be just like this after compile:

```
class A
{
protected:
    A()
    { }
};

class B : private A
{
    using A::A;
public:
    B() : A() {}
};

int main()
{
    auto b = B{};
    return 0;
}
```